# ZF2 How to use str_replace in the view

Tags: php, view, zend-framework2

I want to replace the slash with nothing but in my view this code doesn't work:

```
<?php
    echo str_replace('\\', '', $this->url());
?>
```

Is there anyone who knows the reason?

Comment: how you are getting `\\\` with $this->url()?

Comment: What happens when you do: `var_dump($this->url())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to remove `\\` from string

```
 <?php echo str_replace('\\\\', '', $this->url());  ?>
```

Comment: please provide what url you are getting from `$this->url()`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because __toString isn't triggered when passing `$this->url()` directly as a parameter.

Try the following:

```
<?php echo str_replace('\\', '', (string)$this->url());  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are really looking for this:

```
<?php echo str_replace('/', '', $this->url());  ?>
```